# How to fetch the list of Milestone under the Entitlement Process of the Entitlement using Entitlement Name?

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, unit-test

I am looking to have a SOQL query for the following scenarios?

1. How to fetch the list of `Milestone` under the `Entitlement Process` of the Entitlement using `Entitlement Name` ?
2. Using CaseId fetch the Name Of the Milestones??

> [SELECT Id, Name FROM MilestoneType where Id IN (SELECT
>   MilestoneTypeId FROM CaseMilestone WHERE CaseId = '')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How to fetch the list of Milestone under the Entitlement Process of the Entitlement using Entitlement Name ?

You need to use Metadata API to fetch list of milestones under Entitlement process.

From Entitlement Name you can get `SLAProcessId`, which Entitlement Process Id through SOQL query.

```
SELECT SlaProcessId FROM Entitlement WHERE Name = '<Entitlement Name>';
```

Refer [EntitlementProcess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_entitlementprocess.htm) Metadata API which has `milestones` field referred to `EntitlementProcessMilestoneItem` and from there you can fetch `milestoneName`.

> 2. Using CaseId fetch the Name Of the Milestones??

This SOQL I have given you earlier perfectly works for me.

```
[SELECT Id, Name FROM MilestoneType 
WHERE Id IN 
(SELECT MilestoneTypeId 
FROM CaseMilestone 
WHERE CaseId = '')]
```